# Glassfish JDBCRealm Login Exception

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, glassfish, jdbcrealm

I have a JDBCRealm setup in glasfish 3.1 with oracle11. My web app authentication works fine, but now I'd like to be able to react if someone fails to login 3 times in a row. Looking at my server log I can see that every time the login fails an exception is logged :

```
WARNING: WEB9102: Web Login Failed:
com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.common.LoginException: 
Login failed: Security Exception
```

Do you guys know any way of catching it programmatically in my java code? I tried googling it, but to no avail.

Or maybe you know a better solution altogether? Please share.

Thanks,
Damo

UPDATE:
I need to re-phrase the question (or explain the situation properly). Every time authentication fails I want to log it in my database. To do that I need the username, timestamp, etc. Every time authentication fails the system will check failures count and if it's more than 3 it will lock the user's account. So, I could do it in my loginerror.jsp, but I need the username. Can't find it anywhere :). So far I experimented with a filter, but it appears that you can't filter on j_security_check url-patter (at least not in glassfish 3.1). So really, the main issue here is getting the username of the person that failed the login passed to loginerror.jsp (in any form: attribute, parameter, whatever). Will go and experiment with some java script and form submission.. hehe. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only catch it if you take the login in your hands. Instead of submitting the form to `j_security_check`, you need to submit to a servlet which uses [`HttpServletRequest#login()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#login%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

```
try {
    request.login(username, password);
} catch (ServletException e) {
    // Handle.
}
```

Comment: Fair enough, but I gotta stick to the form login. I'm thinking about setting up a listener maybe. Back to google then :). Thanks!

Comment: You cannot register a filter/listener on `j_security_check` requests.

Comment: Well, I can filter j_security_check if I specify the url-patter to be '/*'. But once I change the url-pattern to '/j_security_check' it fails, i.e. does not filter. grrr.. :D.. oh well.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could specify the form-error-page in web.xml.

You probably could specify a servlet there which redirects the user to the page you want to show.

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bncas/index.html#6nmq2cpkm

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>file</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/error.xhtml</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

Comment: He want to handle the case of 3 login failures in a row, not to handle "a" login failure (I have the impression that he already knows that :) ).

Comment: Yes, but he could probably do this in a Servlet registered as form-error-page, e.g. something like: increase the error counter for this session, check if it is below 3, if yes direct to error page 1, else to error page 2.

Comment: Yes, error jsp is fine and that's what I intend to do :-), but see my update to the question above. Thanks!